# How to not overwrite csv file in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am running python script. But it overwriting the file every time.
Can you please help me how to do this?

example:

```
DF1

Table           Count
case            20
recordtype      50
consumer        70
settlement      150
address         250
bridge          130
```

I ran the process for only 'case' & 'consumer'. Now new count in case and consumer is 80 & 150 
but i am getting the file like this

```
DF1
Table         Count
case          80
consumer      150
```

but i want final result:

```
DF1

Table           Count
case            80
recordtype      50
consumer        150
settlement      150
address         250
bridge          130
```

I am using below code to save the dataframe in file:

```
df_s.to_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt', sep = '|', index= False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose mode=append to append it to your existing csv file.
Check if file is present in path.
If its present, set mode=append else create a new csv file.
And you need to choose header=False to make sure header doesn't appearin append mode.

```
import os.path
if(os.path.isfile('Your path')):
    df_s.to_csv('Your path', sep = '|', mode='a', index= False,header=False)
else:
   df_s.to_csv('/medaff/Scripts/python/count.txt', sep = '|', index= False)
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Your answer is correct but there is some problem. It is adding the same job multiple times. I don't want to add same job in new line. I just want to change the count for that job only.